# How to customize login screen for Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

Tags: 14.04, unity, login, compiz, lightdm

is there a way to customize the login screen for Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS. I want to move my login area of Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS from left side to the middle. After searching in the web i came across [this tutorial](http://linuxg.net/how-to-get-the-old-ubuntu-lockscreen-on-your-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr/) for customizing lock screen in Ubuntu Trusty Tahr. I have installed the CompizConfig Settings Manager in my system but after that i am unable to find this section "*go to Lockscreen and from the drop-down box choose LightDM*"

what i did was

CCSB->Selected **Desktop** from **category** section -> selected **Ubuntu Unity Plugin** -> **General Tab**

But there is no option such as **lockscreen** available in my CCSB

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to install and use **ubuntu-tweak**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

Now start tweaking. Kudoos!